# El entry me devuelve el nro 0 en vez de lo ingresado por el usuario

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hala, estoy teniendo un problma con un codigo que estoy haciendo en python y no se como solucionarlo, busque en varios lados pero no encontre nada. A su vez me gustaría aclarar que si llegan a ver el código entero (que lo dejo al final puesto que el problema lo tengo solo en una parte) y tienen criticas acerca del mismo son completamente bienvenidas.

Hace un mes que arranque a aprender python, ahora estoy comenzando con Tkinter por lo que agarre un Excel que tenia y estoy tratando de hacerlo (el Excel es una planilla con control de movimientos mensuales y stock entre depósitos).
Al principio hice que sea por terminal (https://github.com/GaboLC98/stock-y-movimientos) y ahora lo estoy adaptando a Tkinter. El problema viene cuando quiero que el usuario ingrese con un entry la cantidad de "botellones" (producto de la empresa) que desea cargar a X deposito (si el deposito X no es el deposito madre lo que sucede es que la cantidad se le resta a este ultimo y se le suma al X, en el caso de que el agregado sea al deposito madre solo se le suma a este).

El codigo para el entry es:

```
def selbot():
    #PIDO CANTIDADES Y FECHA
    opcion3=Label(root,text="Cantidad:",font=("Curier 10"))
    opcion3.place(x=255,y=340)
    op2=Entry(root)
    op2.place(x=325,y=342)
    numero=IntVar(op2.get())
    lista.append(numero.get())

    fecha=Label(root,text="Fecha:",font=("Curier 10"))
    fecha.place(x=255,y=370)
    opfecha=Entry(root)
    opfecha.place(x=325,y=372)
    fecha=IntVar(opfecha.get())
    lista.append(fecha.get())
```

Como pueden ver al final de las cantidades y la fecha hay un lista.append(). El motivo de esto (ustedes me dirán si hay una forma mejor de hacerlo) es porque como el código esta dividido en 3 "etapas" que se van activando con un botón esta todo puesto en funciones para enlazarlos a dichos botones. La forma de obtener las varaibles de las diferentes funciones fue armar una lista con dicha info puesto que de otra forma no me dejaba.
Mas allá de esa explicación, lo que sucede es que al imprimir la lista por consola me aparece en las posiciones de cantidad y fecha el nro. 0 y no se como solucionarlo para que me aparezca el numero que ingresa el usuario.

Desde ya muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer.

Les dejo el código completo por si les interesa (si lo ven y encuentran errores de novato las criticas son completamente bienvenidas):

```
from io import open
from tkinter import *

root=Tk() #CREO LA VENTANA
root.title("Stock y movimientos de botellones")
root.geometry("780x600")
root.resizable(0,0)

ficheror=open("actmes.txt","r")#ABRO Y LEO EL FICHERO PARA USAR LA INFO EN LAS CLASES
lectura=ficheror.readlines()
ficheror.close()

def newm(): #CREO NUEVO TXT CON LA INFO ACTUAL
    nombre=input("¿Como desea guardar el mes actual?\n--------> ")
    file=open(nombre,"w")
    info=("FABRICA {},{},{} // DOLORES {},{},{} // CHIVILCOY {},{},{} // CHASCOMUS {},{},{} // RANCHO {},{},{} // GGCHU {},{},{} // CASTELLI {},{},{} //".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad))
    file.write(info)
    file.close()
    ing_manual()

def ing_manual():
    manual=int(input("¿Como desea agregar el stock de FABRICA?\n1- De forma manual\n2-Pasar el stock actual\n--------> "))
    if manual==2:
        file1=open("actmes.txt","w") #SOBREESCRIBO EL TXT ACTUAL
        file1.write("""{}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}""".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
        file1.close()
    elif manual==1:
            bot1=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de botellones de 12 litros IVESS Hogar en stock --------> "))
            bot2=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de botellones de 12 litros IVESS -sodio en stock --------> "))
            bot3=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de botellones de 20 litros IVESS Hogar en stock --------> "))
            file1=open("actmes.txt","w") #MODIFICO EL TXT ACTUAL CON LOS DATOS INGRESADOR POR EL USUARIO
            file1.write("""{}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}""".format(bot1,bot2,bot3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
            file1.close()
    else:
        print("\nOpcion incorrecta... vuelva a intentarlo\n")
        ing_manual()

#DEFINO SUPER CLASE
class botellones_fabrica:
    def __init__(self,nombre,cantidad):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.cantidad=cantidad
    def __str__(self):
        return "NOMBRE: {} \nCANTINDAD: {}".format(self.nombre,self.cantidad)
    def agregar(destino,cant):
        #DEFINO MOVIMIENTOS DE BOTELLONES
        if "Hogar 12lts" in destino.nombre and not "Fabrica" in destino.nombre :
            bot12fa.cantidad-=cant
            destino.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "-Sodio 12lts" in destino.nombre and not "Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot12vfa.cantidad-=cant
            destino.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "Hogar 20lts" in destino.nombre and not "Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot20fa.cantidad-=cant
            destino.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))            
        elif "Hogar 12lts - Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot12fa.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "-Sodio 12lts - Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot12vfa.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "Hogar 20lts - Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot20fa.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        fichero=open("actmes.txt","w")
        texto="""{}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}""".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot20gu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad)
        fichero.write(texto)
        fichero.close()
       
#DEFINO BOTELLONES DE SUPER CLASE
bot12fa=botellones_fabrica("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Fabrica",int(lectura[0]))
bot12vfa=botellones_fabrica("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Fabrica",int(lectura[1]))
bot20fa=botellones_fabrica("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Fabrica",int(lectura[2]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE DOLORES - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_dolores(botellones_fabrica):
    pass   
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE DOLORES     
bot12ds=botellones_dolores("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Dolores",int(lectura[3]))
bot12vds=botellones_dolores("IVESS -Sodio 12lts Dolores",int(lectura[4]))
bot20ds=botellones_dolores("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Dolores",int(lectura[5]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE CHIVILCOY - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_chivilcoy(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE CHIVILCOY
bot12cy=botellones_chivilcoy("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Chivilcoy",int(lectura[6]))
bot12vcy=botellones_chivilcoy("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Chivilcoy",int(lectura[7]))
bot20cy=botellones_chivilcoy("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Chivilcoy",int(lectura[8]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE CHASCOMUS - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_chascomus(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE CHASCOMUS
bot12cs=botellones_chascomus("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Chascomus",int(lectura[9]))
bot12vcs=botellones_chascomus("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Chascomus",int(lectura[10]))
bot20cs=botellones_chascomus("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Chascomus",int(lectura[11]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE RANCHOS - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_ranchos(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE RANCHOS
bot12rs=botellones_ranchos("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Rancho",int(lectura[12]))
bot12vrs=botellones_ranchos("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Rancho",int(lectura[13]))
bot20rs=botellones_ranchos("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Rancho",int(lectura[14]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE GUALEGUAYCHU - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_gualeguaychu(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE GUALEGUAYCHU
bot12gu=botellones_gualeguaychu("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Ggchu",int(lectura[15]))
bot12vgu=botellones_gualeguaychu("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Ggchu",int(lectura[16]))
bot20gu=botellones_gualeguaychu("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Ggchu",int(lectura[17]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE CASTELLI - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_castelli(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE CASTELLI
bot12ci=botellones_castelli("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Castelli",int(lectura[18]))
bot12vci=botellones_castelli("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Castelli",int(lectura[19]))
bot20ci=botellones_castelli("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Castelli",int(lectura[20]))
############################################
#DEFINO LOS DIFERENTES STOCKS COMO LISTAS
class stock_f:
    def __init__(self,stockf):
        self.stockf=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockf.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockf:
            print(x)
class stock_d:
    def __init__(self,stockd):
        self.stockd=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockd.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockd:
            print(x)
class stock_cy:
    def __init__(self,stockcy):
        self.stockcy=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockcy.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockcy:
            print(x)
class stock_cs:
    def __init__(self,stockcs):
        self.stockcs=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockcs.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockcs:
            print(x)
class stock_r:
    def __init__(self,stockr):
        self.stockr=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockr.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockr:
            print(x)
class stock_g:
    def __init__(self,stockg):
        self.stockg=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockg.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockg:
            print(x)
class stock_c:
    def __init__(self,stockc):
        self.stockc=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockc.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockc:
            print(x)
sf=stock_f([])#DEFINO FABRICA
sf.agregar_stock(bot12fa)
sf.agregar_stock(bot12vfa)
sf.agregar_stock(bot20fa)
sd=stock_d([])#DEFINO DOLORES
sd.agregar_stock(bot12ds)
sd.agregar_stock(bot12vds)
sd.agregar_stock(bot20ds)
scy=stock_cy([])#DEFINO CHIVILCOY
scy.agregar_stock(bot12cy)
scy.agregar_stock(bot12vcy)
scy.agregar_stock(bot20cy)
scs=stock_cs([])#DEFINO CHASCOMUS
scs.agregar_stock(bot12cs)
scs.agregar_stock(bot12vcs)
scs.agregar_stock(bot20cs)
sr=stock_r([])#DEFINO RANCHO
sr.agregar_stock(bot12rs)
sr.agregar_stock(bot12vrs)
sr.agregar_stock(bot20rs)
sg=stock_g([])#DEFINO GGCHU
sg.agregar_stock(bot12gu)
sg.agregar_stock(bot12vgu)
sg.agregar_stock(bot20gu)
sc=stock_c([])#DEFINO CASTELLI
sc.agregar_stock(bot12ci)
sc.agregar_stock(bot12vci)
sc.agregar_stock(bot20ci)
#TERMINO DE DEFINIR TODAS LAS LISTAS
def help_s():#AGREGO UN HELP
    print("\n##########MENU HELP##########\nDEPOSITOS: \n1- Deposito frabrica\n2- Deposito Dolores\n3- Deposito Chivilcoy\n4- Deposito Chascomus\n5- Deposito Rancho\n6- Deposito Gualeguaychu\n7- Deposito Castelli")
    print("Se nos pregunta el deposito con el cual queremos trabajar, debemos tipear algun nro segun corresponda\nLuego se nos pregunta por el tipo de botellon que necesitemos y la cantidad\n\n")
    input("Presion cualquier tecla para contnuar---------------->")

lista=[]

#DEFINO EL TITULO PRINCIPAL
Titulo1=Label(root,text="¿Donde desea agregar botellones?",font=("Curier 15"))
Titulo1.pack()

#DEFINO LOS RADIOUTTONS PARA ELEGIR DEPOSITO
opcion=IntVar()
def depositos():
    Fabrica=Radiobutton(root,text="Fabrica",value=1,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Fabrica.place(x=40 , y=40)
    Dolores=Radiobutton(root,text="Dolores",value=2,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Dolores.place(x=140 , y=40)
    Chivolcoy=Radiobutton(root,text="Chivolcoy",value=3,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Chivolcoy.place(x=240 , y=40)
    Chascomus=Radiobutton(root,text="Chascomus",value=4,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Chascomus.place(x=340, y=40)
    Rancho=Radiobutton(root,text="Rancho",value=5,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Rancho.place(x=440 , y=40)
    Ggchu=Radiobutton(root,text="Ggchu",value=6,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Ggchu.place(x=540 , y=40)
    Castelli=Radiobutton(root,text="Castelli",value=7,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Castelli.place(x=640 , y=40)

#DEFINO RADIOBUTTONS PARA PRODUCTOS
opcion2=IntVar()
def botellones():
    bot12=Radiobutton(root,text="12lts IVESS Hogar",value=1,font=("Curier 10"),variable=opcion2)
    bot12.place(x=100 , y=250)
    bot12v=Radiobutton(root,text="12lts IVESS -Sodio",value=2,font=("Curier 10"),variable=opcion2)
    bot12v.place(x=300 , y=250)
    bot20=Radiobutton(root,text="20lts IVESS Hogar",value=3,font=("Curier 10"),variable=opcion2)
    bot20.place(x=500 , y=250)
    #SEGUNDO SIGUIENTE
    sig2=Button(root,text="Siguiente",command=selbot)
    sig2.place(x=350,y=290)

depositos()
#PRIMER SIGUIENTE
sig1=Button(root,text="Siguiente",command=botellones)
sig1.place(x=350,y=75)


def selbot():
    #PIDO CANTIDADES Y FECHA
    opcion3=Label(root,text="Cantidad:",font=("Curier 10"))
    opcion3.place(x=255,y=340)
    op2=Entry(root)
    op2.place(x=325,y=342)
    numero=IntVar(op2.get())
    lista.append(numero.get())

    fecha=Label(root,text="Fecha:",font=("Curier 10"))
    fecha.place(x=255,y=370)
    opfecha=Entry(root)
    opfecha.place(x=325,y=372)
    fecha=IntVar(opfecha.get())
    lista.append(fecha.get())

    if opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot12fa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot12vfa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot20fa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot12ds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot12vds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot20ds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot12cy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot12vcy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot20cy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot12cs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot12vcs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot20cs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot12rs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot12vrs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot20rs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot12gu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot12vgu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot20gu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot12ci
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot12vci
        lista.append(bot.__str__())
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot20ci
        lista.append(bot)
    #DEFINO BOTON PARA "GRABAR"
    siguiente1=Button(root,text="Grabar",command=seldepo,font=("Curier 10"))
    siguiente1.place(x=355 , y=430)

def seldepo():
    if opcion.get()==1:
        depo=botellones_fabrica
    elif opcion.get()==2:
        depo=botellones_dolores
    elif opcion.get()==3:
        depo=botellones_chivilcoy
    elif opcion.get()==4:
        depo=botellones_chascomus
    elif opcion.get()==5:
        depo=botellones_ranchos
    elif opcion.get()==6:
        depo=botellones_gualeguaychu
    elif opcion.get()==6:
        depo=botellones_castelli
    lista.append(depo)
    #DEFINO BOTON PARA FINALIZAR
    siguiente1=Button(root,text="Terminar",command=fin,font=("Curier 10"))
    siguiente1.place(x=350 , y=480)

def fin():
    print(lista)
    lista[3].agregar(lista[2],lista[0])
    alog=open("log.txt","a")
    ltxt="\n Se ingresaron {} {} el dia {}".format(lista[0],lista[2].nombre,lista[1])
    alog.write(ltxt)
    alog.close()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas,

Le estoy echando un ojo a tu código, te cuento lo que te pasa de por qué te da 0:

```
def selbot():
    op2=Entry(root) # Creas Op2
    op2.place(x=325,y=342) # Colocas Op2
    numero=IntVar(op2.get()) # Creas la variable a manejar para tkinter
    lista.append(numero.get()) # Añades a la lista el valor actual de la variable, 0
```

En cambio, en la misma función, más adelante, chequeas el valor de opcion2 que has declarado en otro momento. Tienes que hacer lo mismo aquí y añadir el valor de número desde la función a la que llama el botón siguiente de esta página (seldepo, por lo que veo). Tendrás que hacer esta variable visible por esta función, pero ya sabes hacerlo.

Respecto a cosas de novatos:

¿Por qué haces esto?

```
class stock_f:
    def __init__(self,stockf):
        self.stockf=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockf.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockf:
            print(x)
class stock_d:
    def __init__(self,stockd):
        self.stockd=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockd.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockd:
            print(x)
class stock_cy:
    def __init__(self,stockcy):
        self.stockcy=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockcy.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockcy:
            print(x)
class stock_cs:
    def __init__(self,stockcs):
        self.stockcs=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockcs.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockcs:
            print(x)
class stock_r:
    def __init__(self,stockr):
        self.stockr=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockr.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockr:
            print(x)
class stock_g:
    def __init__(self,stockg):
        self.stockg=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockg.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockg:
            print(x)
class stock_c:
    def __init__(self,stockc):
        self.stockc=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockc.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockc:
            print(x)
```

Es muy raro el caso en el que tengas que tener 10 clases iguales y te valga de algo. Puedes definir solo una y que el resto tire de ahí:

```
class stock:
    def __init__(self): #El parámetro que pasabas por aquí no hacía nada
        self.stock=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stock.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stock:
            print(x)
```

Respecto a la clase "botellones_fabrica" y toda su herencia, aunque es algo más inteligente su uso, puedes obviar tanta clase y tirar desde "botellones_fabrica". Ya tienes en el texto de donde vienen, ten una variable dentro de "botellones_fabrica" que te lo diga.

También en la clase "botellones_fabrica", revisa cómo funciona el [.join de str en la documentación de python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) y el [map también en la misma doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), puedes reducir mucho este tipo de código:

```
         """{}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}  {}""".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot20gu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad)
```

Con algo parecido a:

```
"\n".join(map(str, [bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot20gu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad]))
```

(El \n es un salto de línea de unix, si necesitas uno de windows es \r\n)

Otra cosa que te quitará dolores de cabeza. Los "Ifs" que en otros lenguajes se hacen con "Cases" se pueden hacer con diccionarios. Este código (obvio lo de las clases):

```
if opcion.get()==1:
    depo=botellones_fabrica
elif opcion.get()==2:
    depo=botellones_dolores
elif opcion.get()==3:
    depo=botellones_chivilcoy
elif opcion.get()==4:
    depo=botellones_chascomus
elif opcion.get()==5:
    depo=botellones_ranchos
elif opcion.get()==6:
    depo=botellones_gualeguaychu
elif opcion.get()==6: #Has repetido el 6
    depo=botellones_castelli
```

Se puede hacer así:

```
depo = {1: botellones_fabrica,
        2: botellones_dolores,
        3: botellones_chivilcoy,
        4: botellones_chascomus,
        5: botellones_ranchos,
        6: botellones_gualeguaychu,
        7: botellones_castelli} [opcion.get()]
```

También lo puedes hacer con el otro:

```
    if opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot12fa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot12vfa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot20fa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot12ds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot12vds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot20ds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot12cy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot12vcy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot20cy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot12cs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot12vcs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot20cs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot12rs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot12vrs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot20rs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot12gu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot12vgu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot20gu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot12ci
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot12vci
        lista.append(bot.__str__())
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot20ci
        lista.append(bot)
```

Y verás que es más sencillo de revisar:

```
    bot = {1: {1: bot12fa,
               2: bot12ds,
               3: bot12cy,
               4: bot12cs,
               5: bot12rs,
               6: bot12gu,
               7: bot12ci
               },
           2: {1: bot12vfa,
               2: bot12vds,
               3: bot12vcy,
               4: bot12vcs,
               5: bot12vrs,
               6: bot12vgu,
               7: bot12vci
               },
           3: {1: bot20fa,
               2: bot20ds,
               3: bot20cy,
               4: bot20cs,
               5: bot20rs,
               6: bot20gu,
               7: bot20ci
               }}
    lista.append(bot[opcion2.get()][opcion.get()])
```

Espero que todo vaya bien, que mi aporte haya servido de algo y que aprendas un montón.

Un saludo,

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy a comenzar a usar los diccionarios en vez de todos los ifs, no se me había ocurrido y tiene mucho mas sentido.
Sobre las clases y las documentaciones me voy a poner a ver lo que me dijiste asi comienzo a aplicarlo, me ahorraría MUCHISIMO código

Answer (score 0):

Al final logre solucionar el problema. Lo que hice fue definir por fuera de la funcion una variable IntVar() y a esa variable la agregue al entry como textvariable = variable. Les dejo el codigo por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo:

```
numero=IntVar()
date=StringVar()
def selbot():
    #PIDO CANTIDADES Y FECHA
    opcion3=Label(root,text="Cantidad:",font=("Curier 10"))
    opcion3.place(x=255,y=340)
    op2=Entry(root,textvariable=numero)
    op2.place(x=325,y=342)

    fecha=Label(root,text="Fecha:",font=("Curier 10"))
    fecha.place(x=255,y=370)
    opfecha=Entry(root,textvariable=date)
    opfecha.place(x=325,y=372)
```

De esta forma lo unico que necesitaba hacer era poner numero.get() para que me devuelva lo ingresado por el usuario sin necesidad de usar la lista.
A su vez modifique la estructura del codigo, se los dejo por si les interesa

```
from io import open
from tkinter import *

root=Tk() #CREO LA VENTANA
root.title("Stock y movimientos de botellones")
root.geometry("780x600")
root.resizable(0,0)

ficheror=open("actmes.txt","r")#ABRO Y LEO EL FICHERO PARA USAR LA INFO EN LAS CLASES
lectura=ficheror.readlines()
ficheror.close()

def newm(): #CREO NUEVO TXT CON LA INFO ACTUAL
    nombre=input("¿Como desea guardar el mes actual?\n--------> ")
    file=open(nombre,"w")
    info=("FABRICA {},{},{} // DOLORES {},{},{} // CHIVILCOY {},{},{} // CHASCOMUS {},{},{} // RANCHO {},{},{} // GGCHU {},{},{} // CASTELLI {},{},{} //".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad))
    file.write(info)
    file.close()
    ing_manual()

def ing_manual():
    manual=int(input("¿Como desea agregar el stock de FABRICA?\n1- De forma manual\n2-Pasar el stock actual\n--------> "))
    if manual==2:
        file1=open("actmes.txt","w") #SOBREESCRIBO EL TXT ACTUAL
        file1.write("""{}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}""".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
        file1.close()
    elif manual==1:
            bot1=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de botellones de 12 litros IVESS Hogar en stock --------> "))
            bot2=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de botellones de 12 litros IVESS -sodio en stock --------> "))
            bot3=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de botellones de 20 litros IVESS Hogar en stock --------> "))
            file1=open("actmes.txt","w") #MODIFICO EL TXT ACTUAL CON LOS DATOS INGRESADOR POR EL USUARIO
            file1.write("""{}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}
            {}""".format(bot1,bot2,bot3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
            file1.close()
    else:
        print("\nOpcion incorrecta... vuelva a intentarlo\n")
        ing_manual()

#DEFINO SUPER CLASE
class botellones_fabrica:
    def __init__(self,nombre,cantidad):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.cantidad=cantidad
    def __str__(self):
        return "NOMBRE: {} \nCANTINDAD: {}".format(self.nombre,self.cantidad)


       
#DEFINO BOTELLONES DE SUPER CLASE
bot12fa=botellones_fabrica("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Fabrica",int(lectura[0]))
bot12vfa=botellones_fabrica("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Fabrica",int(lectura[1]))
bot20fa=botellones_fabrica("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Fabrica",int(lectura[2]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE DOLORES - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_dolores(botellones_fabrica):
    pass   
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE DOLORES     
bot12ds=botellones_dolores("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Dolores",int(lectura[3]))
bot12vds=botellones_dolores("IVESS -Sodio 12lts Dolores",int(lectura[4]))
bot20ds=botellones_dolores("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Dolores",int(lectura[5]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE CHIVILCOY - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_chivilcoy(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE CHIVILCOY
bot12cy=botellones_chivilcoy("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Chivilcoy",int(lectura[6]))
bot12vcy=botellones_chivilcoy("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Chivilcoy",int(lectura[7]))
bot20cy=botellones_chivilcoy("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Chivilcoy",int(lectura[8]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE CHASCOMUS - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_chascomus(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE CHASCOMUS
bot12cs=botellones_chascomus("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Chascomus",int(lectura[9]))
bot12vcs=botellones_chascomus("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Chascomus",int(lectura[10]))
bot20cs=botellones_chascomus("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Chascomus",int(lectura[11]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE RANCHOS - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_ranchos(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE RANCHOS
bot12rs=botellones_ranchos("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Rancho",int(lectura[12]))
bot12vrs=botellones_ranchos("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Rancho",int(lectura[13]))
bot20rs=botellones_ranchos("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Rancho",int(lectura[14]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE GUALEGUAYCHU - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_gualeguaychu(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE GUALEGUAYCHU
bot12gu=botellones_gualeguaychu("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Ggchu",int(lectura[15]))
bot12vgu=botellones_gualeguaychu("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Ggchu",int(lectura[16]))
bot20gu=botellones_gualeguaychu("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Ggchu",int(lectura[17]))
############################################
#DEFINO CLASE CASTELLI - corresponde al deposito
class botellones_castelli(botellones_fabrica):
    pass
#DEFINO BOTELLONES (nomenclatura) DE CASTELLI
bot12ci=botellones_castelli("IVESS Hogar 12lts - Castelli",int(lectura[18]))
bot12vci=botellones_castelli("IVESS -Sodio 12lts - Castelli",int(lectura[19]))
bot20ci=botellones_castelli("IVESS Hogar 20lts - Castelli",int(lectura[20]))
############################################
#DEFINO LOS DIFERENTES STOCKS COMO LISTAS
class stock_f:
    def __init__(self,stockf):
        self.stockf=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockf.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockf:
            print(x)
class stock_d:
    def __init__(self,stockd):
        self.stockd=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockd.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockd:
            print(x)
class stock_cy:
    def __init__(self,stockcy):
        self.stockcy=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockcy.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockcy:
            print(x)
class stock_cs:
    def __init__(self,stockcs):
        self.stockcs=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockcs.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockcs:
            print(x)
class stock_r:
    def __init__(self,stockr):
        self.stockr=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockr.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockr:
            print(x)
class stock_g:
    def __init__(self,stockg):
        self.stockg=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockg.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockg:
            print(x)
class stock_c:
    def __init__(self,stockc):
        self.stockc=[]
    def agregar_stock(self,x):
        self.stockc.append(x)
    def ver_stock(self):
        for x in self.stockc:
            print(x)
sf=stock_f([])#DEFINO FABRICA
sf.agregar_stock(bot12fa)
sf.agregar_stock(bot12vfa)
sf.agregar_stock(bot20fa)
sd=stock_d([])#DEFINO DOLORES
sd.agregar_stock(bot12ds)
sd.agregar_stock(bot12vds)
sd.agregar_stock(bot20ds)
scy=stock_cy([])#DEFINO CHIVILCOY
scy.agregar_stock(bot12cy)
scy.agregar_stock(bot12vcy)
scy.agregar_stock(bot20cy)
scs=stock_cs([])#DEFINO CHASCOMUS
scs.agregar_stock(bot12cs)
scs.agregar_stock(bot12vcs)
scs.agregar_stock(bot20cs)
sr=stock_r([])#DEFINO RANCHO
sr.agregar_stock(bot12rs)
sr.agregar_stock(bot12vrs)
sr.agregar_stock(bot20rs)
sg=stock_g([])#DEFINO GGCHU
sg.agregar_stock(bot12gu)
sg.agregar_stock(bot12vgu)
sg.agregar_stock(bot20gu)
sc=stock_c([])#DEFINO CASTELLI
sc.agregar_stock(bot12ci)
sc.agregar_stock(bot12vci)
sc.agregar_stock(bot20ci)
#TERMINO DE DEFINIR TODAS LAS LISTAS
def help_s():#AGREGO UN HELP
    print("\n##########MENU HELP##########\nDEPOSITOS: \n1- Deposito frabrica\n2- Deposito Dolores\n3- Deposito Chivilcoy\n4- Deposito Chascomus\n5- Deposito Rancho\n6- Deposito Gualeguaychu\n7- Deposito Castelli")
    print("Se nos pregunta el deposito con el cual queremos trabajar, debemos tipear algun nro segun corresponda\nLuego se nos pregunta por el tipo de botellon que necesitemos y la cantidad\n\n")
    input("Presion cualquier tecla para contnuar---------------->")

lista=[]

#DEFINO EL TITULO PRINCIPAL
Titulo1=Label(root,text="¿Donde desea agregar botellones?",font=("Curier 15"))
Titulo1.pack()

#DEFINO LOS RADIOUTTONS PARA ELEGIR DEPOSITO
opcion=IntVar()
def depositos():
    Fabrica=Radiobutton(root,text="Fabrica",value=1,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Fabrica.place(x=40 , y=40)
    Dolores=Radiobutton(root,text="Dolores",value=2,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Dolores.place(x=140 , y=40)
    Chivolcoy=Radiobutton(root,text="Chivolcoy",value=3,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Chivolcoy.place(x=240 , y=40)
    Chascomus=Radiobutton(root,text="Chascomus",value=4,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Chascomus.place(x=340, y=40)
    Rancho=Radiobutton(root,text="Rancho",value=5,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Rancho.place(x=440 , y=40)
    Ggchu=Radiobutton(root,text="Ggchu",value=6,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Ggchu.place(x=540 , y=40)
    Castelli=Radiobutton(root,text="Castelli",value=7,font=("Curier 10"),bd=2,variable=opcion)
    Castelli.place(x=640 , y=40)

#DEFINO RADIOBUTTONS PARA PRODUCTOS
opcion2=IntVar()
def botellones():
    bot12=Radiobutton(root,text="12lts IVESS Hogar",value=1,font=("Curier 10"),variable=opcion2)
    bot12.place(x=100 , y=250)
    bot12v=Radiobutton(root,text="12lts IVESS -Sodio",value=2,font=("Curier 10"),variable=opcion2)
    bot12v.place(x=300 , y=250)
    bot20=Radiobutton(root,text="20lts IVESS Hogar",value=3,font=("Curier 10"),variable=opcion2)
    bot20.place(x=500 , y=250)
    #SEGUNDO SIGUIENTE
    sig2=Button(root,text="Siguiente",command=selbot)
    sig2.place(x=350,y=290)

depositos()
#PRIMER SIGUIENTE
sig1=Button(root,text="Siguiente",command=botellones)
sig1.place(x=350,y=75)

numero=IntVar()
date=StringVar()
bot=StringVar()
def selbot():
    #PIDO CANTIDADES Y FECHA
    opcion3=Label(root,text="Cantidad:",font=("Curier 10"))
    opcion3.place(x=255,y=340)
    op2=Entry(root,textvariable=numero)
    op2.place(x=325,y=342)

    fecha=Label(root,text="Fecha:",font=("Curier 10"))
    fecha.place(x=255,y=370)
    opfecha=Entry(root,textvariable=date)
    opfecha.place(x=325,y=372)

    if opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot12fa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot12vfa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==1:
        bot=bot20fa
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot12ds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot12vds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==2:
        bot=bot20ds
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot12cy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot12vcy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==3:
        bot=bot20cy
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot12cs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot12vcs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==4:
        bot=bot20cs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot12rs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot12vrs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==5:
        bot=bot20rs
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot12gu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot12vgu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==6:
        bot=bot20gu
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==1 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot12ci
        lista.append(bot)
    elif opcion2.get()==2 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot12vci
        lista.append(bot.__str__())
    elif opcion2.get()==3 and opcion.get()==7:
        bot=bot20ci
        lista.append(bot)
    #DEFINO BOTON PARA "GRABAR"
    siguiente1=Button(root,text="Grabar",command=seldepo,font=("Curier 10"))
    siguiente1.place(x=355 , y=430)

depo=Variable()
def seldepo():
    if opcion.get()==1:
        depo=botellones_fabrica
    elif opcion.get()==2:
        depo=botellones_dolores
    elif opcion.get()==3:
        depo=botellones_chivilcoy
    elif opcion.get()==4:
        depo=botellones_chascomus
    elif opcion.get()==5:
        depo=botellones_ranchos
    elif opcion.get()==6:
        depo=botellones_gualeguaychu
    elif opcion.get()==6:
        depo=botellones_castelli
    lista.append(depo)
    #DEFINO BOTON PARA FINALIZAR
    siguiente1=Button(root,text="Terminar",command=agregar,font=("Curier 10"))
    siguiente1.place(x=350 , y=480)

def agregar():
        alog=open("log.txt","a")
        ltxt="\n Se ingresaron {} {} el dia {}".format(numero.get(),lista[0].nombre,date.get())
        alog.write(ltxt)
        alog.close()
        destino=lista[0]
        cant=numero.get()
        #DEFINO MOVIMIENTOS DE BOTELLONES
        if "Hogar 12lts" in destino.nombre and not "Fabrica" in destino.nombre :
            bot12fa.cantidad-=cant
            destino.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "-Sodio 12lts" in destino.nombre and not "Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot12vfa.cantidad-=cant
            destino.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "Hogar 20lts" in destino.nombre and not "Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot20fa.cantidad-=cant
            destino.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))            
        elif "Hogar 12lts - Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot12fa.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "-Sodio 12lts - Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot12vfa.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        elif "Hogar 20lts - Fabrica" in destino.nombre:
            bot20fa.cantidad+=cant
            print("Se agregaron {}".format(cant))
        fichero=open("actmes.txt","w")
        texto="""{}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}
        {}""".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot20gu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad)
        fichero.write(texto)
        fichero.close()

def fin():
    print(lista)
    lista[0].agregar(lista[1],numero.get())
    alog=open("log.txt","a")
    ltxt="\n Se ingresaron {} {} el dia {}".format(lista[0],lista[2].nombre,lista[1])
    alog.write(ltxt)
    alog.close()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Puedes reducir muchooo código

Comment: Gracias, otro usuario analizo el codigo y me dio muchas recomendaciones que voy a empezar a aplicar

Comment: EL `.format()` lo puedes reducir haciendo uso de los *f-strings*