# Entry devuelve valor vacío o nro 0 en segundo y tercer root

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7, python-requests

estoy practicando con Tkinter, hace un mes arranque con Python y estoy teniendo un problema el cual hace unos dias pude solucionar pero esta vez no se que sucede que no lo logro hacer.
El problema es el siguiente:
Saque la idea de un excel para armar un código el cual consta de una empresa con deposito principal y otros depósitos en ciertas localidades. Básicamente es un control de stock en el principal y control de movimientos mensuales a los distintos depósitos.
Al ser un programa mensual llega un momento donde la info de los depósitos se guarda en un txt y la info del principal se mantiene intacta (puesto que, como dije antes, solo en este se controla el stock). Por lo cual para hacer esto cree un menu donde se encuentra la opcion "Nuevo mes"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al apretar en dicha opción se abre una nueva ventana con el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el usuario ingrese un nombre para el archivo (ej. Mayo 2021) y que se guarde toda la info de los depósitos en ese archivo. El código es el siguiente *(utilizo from io import open para los ficheros)*:

```
name_mes=StringVar()
def newm(): #CREO VENTANA NUEVA Y PIDO NOMBRE PARA GUARDAR LA INFO ACT
    root2=Tk()
    root2.tittle="Nuevo mes"
    root2.geometry("300x300")
    nombre_label=Label(root2,text="¿Como desea guardar el archivo actual?")
    nombre_label.pack()
    nombre=Entry(root2,textvariable=name_mes)
    nombre.pack()
    guardar_r2=Button(root2,text="Guardar",command=new_file)
    guardar_r2.pack()
    root2.mainloop()
def new_file():#GUARDO CON EL NOMBRE DEL ENTRY ANT LOS DATOS ACT
    print("Comenzando creacion de {}...".format(name_mes.get()))
    file=open(name_mes.get(),"w")
    info=("FABRICA {},{},{} // DOLORES {},{},{} // CHIVILCOY {},{},{} // CHASCOMUS {},{},{} // RANCHO {},{},{} // GGCHU {},{},{} // CASTELLI {},{},{} //".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad))
    file.write(info)
    file.close()
    file1=open("actmes.txt","w")
    file1.write("\r".join(map(str,[bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])))
    print("Info guardada")
    file1.close()
```

Pd: Chascomus, Dolores, etc son localidades.

Hay un print en def new_file que es una prueba para poder ver si se esta tomando lo que ingresa el usuario y no esta sucediendo. No logo ver donde esta el error puesto que la variable la estoy definiendo como StringVar() por fuera de la primer def para que new_file pueda tomarla pero no hay caso.

Lo mismo me sucede con la opción "Ingresar stock" de la primer imagen. La idea de esto es darle al usuario la posibilidad de ingresar un stock de forma manual como método de ajuste pero me devuelve solo el nro 0. Dejo el código y una img de la ventana continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Se que no son las ventanas mas lindas pero bueno, me interesa corregir este error*

(Los botellones son los productos de la empresa)

```
hogarazul=IntVar()
sodio=IntVar()
hogar20azul=IntVar()
def ing_manual():#CREO NUEVA VENTANA Y PIDO INFO POR ENTRY
    root3=Tk()
    root3.geometry("300x300")
    root3.tittel="Ing. de stock"
    ingreso=Label(root3,text="Ingrese el stock de: BOTELLONES 12LTS IVESS HOGAR")
    ingreso.pack()
    entrying1=Entry(root3,textvariable=hogarazul)
    entrying1.pack()
    ingreso2=Label(root3,text="Ingrese el stock de: BOTELLONES 12LTS IVESS -SODIO")
    ingreso2.pack()
    entrying2=Entry(root3,textvariable=sodio)
    entrying2.pack()
    ingreso3=Label(root3,text="Ingrese el stock de: BOTELLONES 20LTS IVESS HOGAR")
    ingreso3.pack()
    entrying3=Entry(root3,textvariable=hogar20azul)
    entrying3.pack()
    guardar_r3=Button(root3,text="Guardar",command=ing_manuel_file)
    guardar_r3.pack()
    root3.mainloop()
def ing_manuel_file():#SOBREESCRIBO EL TXT ACTUAL CON LOS DATOS DEL ENTRY ANT
    file1=open("actmes.txt","w")
    file1.write("\r".join(map(str,[hogarazul.get(),sodio.get(),hogar20azul.get(),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])))
    print("Info gurardada")
    file1.close()
```

Comment: hay varias preguntas relacionadas a lo mismo

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [El entry me devuelve el nro 0 en vez de lo ingresado por el usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455303/el-entry-me-devuelve-el-nro-0-en-vez-de-lo-ingresado-por-el-usuario)

Comment: Esa pregunta es la cual hablo al principio. Logre solucionarlo pero ahora no me funciona: Lo que debía hacer antes es usar textvariable, definir la variable como IntVar o StringVar y luego usar .get() para obtener lo que se almaceno en la variable. El problema es que hice eso pero ahora no me funciona y no se porque. No se si capaz tiene que ver por ser en una ventana nueva o algo asi, es la unica diferencia que encuentro

Comment: lo siento no me había percatado que eras el mismo

Comment: No te preocupes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución asique voy a explicarlo por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo:
Lo único que hay que hacer es definir a la ventana no como Tk(), sino como Toplebel(). Les dejo el código de como quedo

```
name_mes=StringVar()
def newm(): #CREO VENTANA NUEVA Y PIDO NOMBRE PARA GUARDAR LA INFO ACT
    root2=Toplevel()
    root2.tittle="Nuevo mes"
    root2.geometry("300x300")
    nombre_label=Label(root2,text="¿Como desea guardar el archivo actual?")
    nombre_label.pack()
    nombre=Entry(root2,textvariable=name_mes)
    nombre.pack()
    guardar_r2=Button(root2,text="Guardar",command=new_file)
    guardar_r2.pack()
    root2.mainloop()
def new_file():#GUARDO CON EL NOMBRE DEL ENTRY ANT LOS DATOS ACT
    file=open(name_mes.get(),"w")
    info=("FABRICA {},{},{} // DOLORES {},{},{} // CHIVILCOY {},{},{} // CHASCOMUS {},{},{} // RANCHO {},{},{} // GGCHU {},{},{} // CASTELLI {},{},{} //".format(bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,bot12ds.cantidad,bot12vds.cantidad,bot20ds.cantidad,bot12cy.cantidad,bot12vcy.cantidad,bot20cy.cantidad,bot12cs.cantidad,bot12vcs.cantidad,bot20cs.cantidad,bot12rs.cantidad,bot12vrs.cantidad,bot20rs.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12gu.cantidad,bot12vgu.cantidad,bot12ci.cantidad,bot12vci.cantidad,bot20ci.cantidad))
    file.write(info)
    file.close()
    file1=open("actmes.txt","w")
    file1.write("\r".join(map(str,[bot12fa.cantidad,bot12vfa.cantidad,bot20fa.cantidad,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])))
    print("Info guardada")
    file1.close()
```

Lo mismo con el entry int:

```
hogarazul=IntVar()
sodio=IntVar()
hogar20azul=IntVar()
def ing_manual():#CREO NUEVA VENTANA Y PIDO INFO POR ENTRY
    root3=Toplevel()
    root3.geometry("300x300")
    root3.tittel="Ing. de stock"
    ingreso=Label(root3,text="Ingrese el stock de: BOTELLONES 12LTS IVESS HOGAR")
    ingreso.pack()
    entrying1=Entry(root3,textvariable=hogarazul)
    entrying1.pack()
    ingreso2=Label(root3,text="Ingrese el stock de: BOTELLONES 12LTS IVESS -SODIO")
    ingreso2.pack()
    entrying2=Entry(root3,textvariable=sodio)
    entrying2.pack()
    ingreso3=Label(root3,text="Ingrese el stock de: BOTELLONES 20LTS IVESS HOGAR")
    ingreso3.pack()
    entrying3=Entry(root3,textvariable=hogar20azul)
    entrying3.pack()
    guardar_r3=Button(root3,text="Guardar",command=ing_manuel_file)
    guardar_r3.pack()
    root3.mainloop()
def ing_manuel_file():#SOBREESCRIBO EL TXT ACTUAL CON LOS DATOS DEL ENTRY ANT
    file1=open("actmes.txt","w")
    file1.write("\r".join(map(str,[hogarazul.get(),sodio.get(),hogar20azul.get(),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])))
    print("Info gurardada")
    file1.close()
```

Mas info sobre Toplevel(): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-toplevel-widget/